# How to insert cursor at proper position in backspace in quill?

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm using inline mention blot in quill and while setting the selection I'm using below code to do set Selection.

```
this.quill.deleteText(this.mentionCharPos, this.cursorPos - this.mentionCharPos, Quill.sources.API); 
this.quill.insertText(this.mentionCharPos, mentionChar, "mention", render.id, Quill.sources.USER);
this.quill.insertText(this.mentionCharPos + name.length + 1, " ", 'mention', false, Quill.sources.USER);
this.quill.setSelection(this.mentionCharPos + name.length + 2, 0, Quill.sources.SILENT);
```

**this.mentionCharPos** --> @ position 
**name** --> mention Name (eg: satya)

When the text got inserted into to the editor at that time the cursor position is at proper place when I do backspace then the cursor itself was hiding and if give space it was showing at the end of the editor.

I'm adding the code of my mention blot as well.

```
import Quill from 'quill';

const Inline = Quill.import('blots/inline');


class MentionBlot extends Inline {
  static create(id) {
const node = super.create();
node.dataset.id = id;
node.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
return node;
}

 static value(domNode) {
  return domNode.dataset;
}
 static formats(node) {
  return node.dataset.id;
 }
 format(name, value) {
  if (name === "mention" && value) {
      this.domNode.setAttribute("data-id", 
value);
  } else {
      super.format(name, value);
  }
}
 formats() {
   const formats = super.formats();
   formats['mention'] = 
   MentionBlot.formats(this.domNode);
  return formats;
  }
  }

  MentionBlot.blotName = 'mention';
  MentionBlot.tagName = 'span';
  MentionBlot.className = 'mention';

  Quill.register({
  'formats/mention': MentionBlot
  });
```

How to show the cursor position at proper and one more thing if I make **contenteditable** as true it is working fine. When I give **contenteditable** as false I'm facing this problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kmmmy1gsidggxt/Screen%20Recording%202019-03-07%20at%2010.08%20AM.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution, insert a space after insert the mention:

```
insertEmbed(range.index, 'mention', value, 'user');
insertText(range.index + 1, "\u00a0", 'user');
```

It's ok.

Comment: For me, inserting `\u00a0` causes a line break in the editor which I cannot seem to override, don't suppose you have come across this?